# Stripe Connect Python Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-connect

```
class VendorUser(models.Model):
    email = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    business_owner = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, blank=True) # validators should be a list
    stripe_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('vendor')
        verbose_name_plural = _('vendors')

def stripe_auth(request):
    params = {
        "response_type": "code",
        "scope": "read_write",
        "client_id": "ca_ANdfv3rlK7967868089609oXuBYqGYiq5"
    }
    # Build a URL to send them off to.  Redirect them to this URL
    stripe_connect_service = OAuth2Service(
    client_id='ca_ANdfv3rlKvpOU680669-696-YqGYiq5',
    client_secret='sk_test_55080569t096-9-69-967-9-9ZpSX',
    name='stripe',
    authorize_url='https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize',
    )

    url = stripe_connect_service.get_authorize_url(**params)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url    

def stripe_callback(request):

    client_secret = STRIPE_API_KEY
    # the temporary code returned from stripe
    user = request.user
    code = request.GET.get('code', '')
    # identify what we are going to ask for from stripe
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'client_secret': clientsecret,
        'client_id': clientid,
        'code': code
    }

    print(data)
    # Get the access_token using the code provided
    url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token'
    resp= requests.post(url, params=data)

    stripe_payload = json.loads(resp.text)

    # process the returned json object from stripe
    print(stripe_payload)

    stripe_user_id = stripe_payload['stripe_user_id']

    user.stripe_user_id = stripe_user_id
    print(stripe_user_id)
    user.save()
```

I'm signing up my users via django allauth, I have a custom signup form and overwrite the base allauth SignupView to sign up user by user type Vendor. In the the vendors landing page I present a stripe connect button, everything is working after following stripe docs and I get the response json with all the required info and save the returned stripe_user_id against the my CustomUser Model, instead of just saving this against my CustomUser, I would like to be able to save the stripe_user_id against my VendorUser.

I am not sure how to grab my Vendor user from user=request.user in the stripe_callback function.

Any input or help on this from you guys would be great.

Comment: Well you don't have any code to save it locally. But what problems are you having writing some? It would just be standard Django ORM code.

Comment: I originally tried saving against stripe_id I had set in my users models, but kept getting: stripe_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self', still learning so not sure if I'm approaching it wrong, others have suggested passing along a token that represents the user with the state parameter but I've seen other replies saying this approach is not correct either.

Comment: edited code, and question after successfully save the stripe connect info against my user, still need some help to get it saving on a connected profile type model.